# Como se faz um socket que conecta realmente com outros computadores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, cliente-servidor

Eu tentei fazer um socket em Python 3.5.1, porém quando fui testar, ele só se conecta comigo. Tentei conectar com outro computador (do meu amigo), porém ele não conecta. Alguém sabe como se faz um socket que realmente conecta?

Caso alguém queira ver, aqui está o meu socket problemático: http://pastebin.com/Z01Fp71K

```python
#Cliente
import socket
HOST = 'Aqui eu coloco o ip'
PORT = 5000
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dest = (HOST, PORT)
tcp.connect(dest)
print('Para sair use CTRL+X\n')
msg = input()
while msg != '\x18':
    tcp.send(msg)
    msg = input()
tcp.close()
```

```python
#Servidor
import socket
HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
orig = (HOST, PORT)
tcp.bind(orig)
tcp.listen(1)
while True:
    con, cliente = tcp.accept()
    print('Concetado por', cliente)
    while True:
        msg = con.recv(1024)
        if not(msg): break
        print(cliente, msg)
    print('Finalizando conexao do cliente', cliente)
    con.close()
```

Comment: Se funcionou com você provavelmente irá funcionar com seu amigo também. O que deve estar acontecendo é que a porta 5000 deve estar bloqueada no firewall do PC do seu amigo. Pesquise sobre como liberar portas no firewall do Windows (ou outro sistema operacional) que tem no PC dele.

Comment: Sim eu pesquisei isso e continua sem funcionar

Answer (score 2):

Aqui funcionou perfeitamente bem, inclusive rodando o servidor num computador na Internet, e usando um HOST com nome em vez de IP no cliente.

O servidor que você tentou está pingando? Às vezes os computadores de uma mesma rede não são acessíveis, seja por problemas do access point (um desliga-religa resolve), seja porque o access point esteja com isolation ativado (impede um computador de conectar com outro da mesma rede por questões de segurança, como em Wi-Fi pública).

O único problema que enfrentei ao digitar algo para o cliente enviar foi o seguinte:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli", line 11, in <module>
    tcp.send(msg)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Isso se resolve trocando a linha do tcp.send(msg) por

```
tcp.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))
```